# SonarLint 2.5 on Eclipse, analyze changes in jazz SCM

Tags: eclipse, sonarlint, ibm-jazz

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen with RTC plugin (on Windows 7), which provides integration to Jazz SCM.

After installing SonarLint 2.5.0, I have tried to analyze changed files by doing:

- right click on project -> sonarlint -> analyze changed files

But no issues are displayed, and the following message is shown in SonarLint console: "No changed files found".

The project I'm trying to analyze is connected to Jazz and has several files with issues in SonarQube.

Project in Eclipse is properly bound to project in SonarQube server

Any ideas what is wrong with my setup? Should I change/install something in my SonarQube server?

I have installed jazz plugin in the server, but it seems it makes no difference.

Regards

Jose

Answer (score 1):

SonarLint relies on RepositoryProvider to implement the [getSubscriber](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fteam%2Fcore%2FRepositoryProvider.html&anchor=getSubscriber--) method to collect list of changed files. It seems that RTC plugin doesn't implement it so we don't have a way to make the feature work for you.

But I admit this could be clearer to I have created a ticket to notify user when trying to use the feature with an unsupported RepositoryProvider:
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLE-145